# Webscraping with BeautifulSoup, getting empty list

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm practicing webscraping by getting basic weather data like the daily high/low temperature from https://www.wunderground.com/  (random zipcode searched).

I've tried various variations of my code but it keeps returning an empty list where the temperature should be. I honestly just don't know enough to pinpoint where i'm going wrong. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
response=requests.get('https://www.wunderground.com/cgi-bin/findweather/getForecast?query=76502')
response_data = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
results=response_data.select("strong.high")
```

I've also tried doing the following along with various other variations:

```
results = response_data.find_all('strong', class_ = 'high')
results = response_data.select('div.small_6 columns > strong.high' )
```

Comment: The content is rendered at runtime. So you do not obtain it with `requests`. You better use a browser that fetches JavaScript, JSON, etc. and updates the DOM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This data you want to parse is being dynamically created by JavaScript, `requests` can't handle that. You should use [**`selenium`**](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) together with [**`PhantomJS`**](http://phantomjs.org/download.html) or any other driver. Below is an example using `selenium` and [**`Chromedriver`**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url='https://www.wunderground.com/cgi-bin/findweather/getForecast?query=76502'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
html = driver.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
```

Inspecting the elements, the lowest, the highest and the current temperature can be find using:

```
high = soup.find('strong', {'class':'high'}).text
low = soup.find('strong', {'class':'low'}).text
now = soup.find('span', {'data-variable':'temperature'}).find('span').text
```

---

```
>>> low, high, now
('25', '37', '36.5')
```

Comment: Alright thank you! I didn't even know about dynamic rendering before this