# Selecting the right CSS tags for scrapy

Tags: python, html, css, scrapy, screen-scraping

I am trying to scrape this page here:
http://www.a1lockerrental.com/self-storage/mo/st-louis/4427-meramec-bottom-rd-facility/unit-sizes-prices#/units?category=all

Here is my code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from testtest.items import TesttestItem
import datetime

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "A1storage"

    allowed_domains = ['https://www.a1lockerrental.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.a1lockerrental.com/self-storage/mo/st-
        louis/4427-meramec-bottom-rd-facility/unit-sizes-prices#/units?
        category=all']

    def parse(self, response):
        info = response.css('buttons')

        for i in info:

            yield {


                "special": i.css(".special-text").extract_first(),
                "rate": i.css(".active .cat-price").extract(),
                "size": i.css(".sss-unit-size::text").extract(),
                "types": i.css(".sss-unit-amenitie 
                       span::text").extract_first()

               }
```

No matter what I change the selector to in the response variable I return nothing. I think something is wrong with the HTML of the website itself but I am not skilled enough to understand it.

Comment: The data you want to parse is being created by JavaScript, have a look at `selenium` for parsing dynamically generated content.

Comment: @Vinícius Aguiar Thank you ill have a look

Comment: Of course looking at the docs is good, but I [answered a question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45537682/5103802) yesterday about this. It should be good to have a look.