# How should I scrape data from a page that has a "minimize-able" section?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, lxml

I am a novice to BeautifulSoup, and am trying to scrape data from a page that has a section that can be minimized by the person browsing the page. When I looked into the HTML code of the page, I found something like this below.

[image]

To extract the table data, I am using the following code, but I am unable to extract data from the table.

```
webpage = "www.webpage.com"
webOpen = urllib2.urlopen(webpage).read()
webSoup = BeautifulSoup(webOpen, "lxml")
tabData = webSoup.find("div", {"class": "cr_cashflow_table"})
tabData = tabData.find_all('tr')
```

I also tried the following, but it seems like I am still unable to extract the data within the table.

```
webpage = "www.webpage.com"
webOpen = urllib2.urlopen(webpage).read()
webSoup = BeautifulSoup(webOpen, "lxml")
tabData = webSoup.find("div", {"class": "cr_cashflow_table", "style": "display: block;"})
tabData = tabData.find_all('tr')
```

If I am doing something wrong, please advise.

Comment: Your code should work, it could be the case that the content is being generated by JavaScript, and  `urllib` can't handle that.

Comment: @ViníciusAguiar might be right here -- try loading the page with JS off and see whether the table is generated. Also check `webOpen`'s contents (and `tabData` before you do the `find_all`) and make sure the table is in there.

Comment: @ViníciusAguiar You're right! With JS off, the table doesn't load.

Comment: Is there something else that can be done to solve this?

Comment: Yes, you could use `selenium` and `ChromeDriver`, I've answered a question not long ago that answered something like this, you can give a read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45537682/5103802

Comment: @ViníciusAguiar Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following code that mimics yours, but I just changed the url:

```
webpage = "www.cnn.com" 
webOpen = urllib2.urlopen(webpage).read()
```

I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 423, in open
    protocol = req.get_type()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 285, in get_type
    raise ValueError, "unknown url type: %s" % self.__original
ValueError: unknown url type: www.cnn.com
```

So it appears that "www.cnn.com" is not a valid url (or maybe because it is a fake new :D ), in order to fix it, I did prepend http, like so: "http://www.cnn.com" and able to get the html doc. Did you try first if urllib2 returned the html document without the http in your url?

I hope this helps.